# V + n-janai vs -ne vs -n-desu-ne

Tags: particles, verbs, formality, parts-of-speech, casual

What's the difference between these 3 forms of a verb:

```
1) 勝てるんじゃない 

2) 勝てるね 

3) 勝てるんですね
```

?

Comment: なんで３つ目だけ丁寧形なんですか？「勝てるんだね」じゃなくて。

Comment: @Schokolade -- replace with "n da ne" if you want to

Answer (score 1):

勝てるんじゃない is "Ah, you can win, after all".

勝てるんじゃない？ is "I guess you can win".

勝てるね is "As far as I see, they can win".

勝てるね？ is "You can win, right? (Just say "yes"!)".

勝てるんですね is "Actually, we can win".

勝てるんですね？ is "So, according to your words, we can win, right?".

Comment: thx. it's still unclear what the degree of confidence in each case, you can you add it please? from lowest to highest.

Comment: They are not comparable because they are used in different situations.